# connecting to Radiostream in Android: status Network error

Tags: android, android-emulator, internet-radio

first, I'm new to Java and Android development, but I'm trying to run the RadioStreams SDK for Android from binpress. I've attached the example code and the bugs that I'm getting from LogCat in the eclipse console. I'm really just trying to figure out why the example won't work. My long term goal is to integrate this into Titanium.

I know this question might be obscure, but any general information on connecting to or streaming a .pls or m3u file would be greatly appreciated.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final String TAG = "RsModule";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final HTTPRadio radio;
    try {
        radio = new HTTPRadio(new URI("http://mfm.ice.infomaniak.ch/playlists/mfm-64.aac.m3u"));
        radio.play();

        radio.setRadioChangeListener(new RadioChangeListener() {
            public void radioStateChanged(final RadioState state) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            switch (state) {
                            case RADIO_STATE_BUFFERING:
                                Log.d(TAG,"Status: Buffering");
                                break;
                            case RADIO_STATE_CONNECTING:
                                Log.d(TAG,"Status: Connecting");
                                break;
                            case RADIO_STATE_PLAYING:
                                Log.d(TAG,"Status: Playing");
                                break;
                            case RADIO_STATE_STOPPED:
                                Log.d(TAG,"Status: Stopped");
                                break;
                            case RADIO_STATE_ERROR:
                                switch (radio.getRadioError()) {
                                case RADIO_ERROR_PLAYLIST_PARSING:
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Status: Playlist Parsing Error");
                                    break;
                                case RADIO_ERROR_DECODING:
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Status: Decoding Error");
                                    break;
                                case RADIO_ERROR_NETWORK_ERROR:
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Status: Network Error");
                                    break;
                                case RADIO_ERROR_FILE_STREAM_OPEN:
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Status: Stream Open Error");
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Status: Error");
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }

            public void radioMetadataChanged(final IcyMetadata metadata) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Now Playing: " + metadata.radioTitle);
                        }
                    });
             }

        });

    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

LogCat Console

04-25 20:25:36.987: I/ActivityManager(60): Starting activity: Intent {       act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.rs/.MainActivity }

04-25 20:25:37.007: I/ActivityManager(60): Start proc com.example.rs for activity com.example.rs/.MainActivity: pid=773 uid=10037 gids={}

04-25 20:25:37.037: D/AndroidRuntime(767): Shutting down VM

04-25 20:25:37.037: D/dalvikvm(767): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

04-25 20:25:37.097: I/AndroidRuntime(767): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed

04-25 20:25:37.678: D/dalvikvm(773): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.rs/lib/libradiostreams.so 0x43e37910

04-25 20:25:37.698: D/dalvikvm(773): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.rs/lib/libradiostreams.so 0x43e37910

04-25 20:25:37.698: D/dalvikvm(773): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.rs/lib/libradiostreams.so 0x43e37910, skipping init

04-25 20:25:37.708: I/RadioStreams(773): Parsing State: /playlists/mfm-64.aac.m3u

04-25 20:25:37.937: I/ActivityManager(60): Displayed activity com.example.rs/.MainActivity: 935 ms (total 935 ms)

04-25 20:25:38.287: D/RadioStreams(773): Status: Network Error

04-25 20:25:43.147: D/dalvikvm(120): GC_EXPLICIT freed 702 objects / 39184 bytes in 134ms

04-25 20:25:48.198: D/dalvikvm(288): GC_EXPLICIT freed 83 objects / 3896 bytes in 132ms

04-25 20:25:53.257: D/dalvikvm(279): GC_EXPLICIT freed 172 objects / 11936 bytes in 132ms

04-25 20:29:14.911: D/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

04-25 20:34:14.958: D/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: Looks like a network error of some sort.  FIrst off, do you have the proper permissions (ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and INTERNET)?

Comment: yeah I still get the same result.